# Symfony 1.4 doctrine yml set default field value with another field's value

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, field, default

```
Table:
    field_1:
      type: decimal(6)
      scale: 2
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      notnull: true 
    field_2:
      type: decimal(6)
      scale: 2
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      notnull: true
      default: field_1
```

Some articles tell me that this is not possible, that I need to do it with PHP, but where exactly? in the lib>model>doctrine>base folder? The little voice in my head is saying: you have no other choice :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some good sleeping I got it. It was under lib>model>doctrine>Table.class.php

```
public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null) {
        if ($this->isNew() && !$this->getField2()) {
            $this->setField2($this->getField1());
        }
        return parent::save($conn);
    }
```

BUT!... It doesn't work with my yml fixtures. Any ideas to make it work with my fixtures?
[Laziness talking].